# Find all numbers a and b such that the matrix A is orthogonal

Tags: matrices, orthogonality, diagonalization

> Find all numbers $a$ and $b$ such that the matrix $$\begin{equation} A = \begin{bmatrix} a+b & b-a \\ a-b & b+a\end{bmatrix},\end{equation}$$ is orthogonal.

I've gotten to 
$$\begin{bmatrix} a+b & b-a \\ a-b & b+a\end{bmatrix} * \begin{bmatrix} a+b & a-b \\ b-a & b+a\end{bmatrix} =
\begin{bmatrix} 2a^2 + 2b^2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2a^2 + 2b^2 \end{bmatrix}$$
Therefore
\begin{equation} a = -b \end{equation}
Unsure where to go from here.

Comment: Don't you go to $2a^2+2b^2=1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ is orthogonal $ \iff \begin{bmatrix} 2a^2 + 2b^2 & 0 \\ 0 & 2a^2 + 2b^2 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix} \iff a^2+b^2=\frac{1}{2}$.